# Positioning two variable-width inline-blocks relatively to each other

Tags: html, css

I have two variable-width elements that I'm trying to position the following way:

1. If they fit next to each other on the screen or in their common container, I want them align to the opposite sides of it (i.e. the second one aligned to right).
2. If they don't, I want them one above the other, but both aligned to the left.

Something as simple as:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    I'm a variable width left element
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; float:right;">
    I'm right-floating if there's space
  </div>
</div>
```

takes care of the first case, but obviously when the container is small enough for the second div to be rendered below the first one, it's still right-floating which is not what I want.

Is this even possible with pure CSS? I can't use media queries because of unknown/variable widths.

Comment: CSS has a lot of holes (desirable layouts that cannot be expressed with pure CSS).  It _might_ be possible if you float the first box left, (play with `display:block` as well) but I've found that a little Javascript is often needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This layout and behavior is possible *without media queries* and *pure CSS* using [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

**HTML**

```
<!-- horizontal alignment when two boxes fit -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="box box2"><span>2</span></div>
</div>

<!-- vertical alignment when two boxes don't fit -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box3"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="box box4"><span>2</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 700px; /* for demo only; can be relative length, as well */
}

.box1 { width: 100px; }
.box2 { width: 150px; }
.box3 { width: 400px; }
.box4 { width: 500px; }
```

[image]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ax4kvL6q/5/)

NOTES:

- When there is enough space to fit both variable-width elements on the same row, they are aligned at opposite ends of the container with [**`justify-content: space-between`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276).
- When there is *not* enough space to fit both elements, they wrap with [**`flex-wrap: wrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) and align-left because the `justify-content: space-between` rule will left-align an element when it is alone on the row.

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*